# glViewport incorrectly mapping normal coordinates to window coordinates?

Tags: opengl, racket

I thought I could make opengl map the coordinates (-1, -1) and (1, 1) to the pixels (0,0) and (width,height) with these calls:

```
(gl-viewport 0 0 width height)
```

```
(gl-ortho -1 1 -1 1 -1 1)
```

However a rectangle drawn from (-1,-1) to (1,1) only reaches across two thirds of the window's left and bottom edges. I can fix that by using

```
(gl-viewport 0 0 (* 3/2 width) (* 3/2 height))
```

but this doesn't seem correct to me. What am I doing wrong?

This is the snippet for DrRacket

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/class)
(require racket/gui/base)
(require sgl)
(require sgl/gl-vectors)

(define game-canvas%
  (class canvas%
    (inherit refresh with-gl-context swap-gl-buffers)

    (super-new)

    (define (next x)
      (modulo (+ 1 x) 100))

    (define x-factor 0)

    (define/override (on-paint)
      (with-gl-context
       (lambda ()
         (gl-clear-color 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0)
         (gl-clear 'color-buffer-bit 'depth-buffer-bit)
         (gl-color 1 1 0) (gl-rect -1 -1 (+ -1 (* 2 x-factor 1/100)) 1)
         (swap-gl-buffers)
         (gl-flush))))

    (define/public (STEP)
      (set! x-factor (next x-factor))
      (refresh)
      (sleep/yield 1/60)
      (queue-callback (lambda _ (send this STEP) #f)))

    (define/override (on-event e)
      (when (is-a? e mouse-event%)
        (when (eq? (send e get-event-type) 'left-down)
          (exit 0))))

    (define/override (on-size width height)
      (with-gl-context
       (lambda ()
         (let ((aspect (/ width height)))
           ;(gl-viewport 0 0 width height)
           (gl-viewport 0 0 (* 3/2 width) (* 3/2 height))
           (gl-matrix-mode 'projection)
           (gl-load-identity)
           (gl-ortho (* aspect -1) (* aspect 1) -1 1 -1 1)
           (gl-enable 'depth-test))))
      (refresh))))

(module+ main
  (define-values (W H) (get-display-size #t))
  (define f (new frame%
                 [style '(no-resize-border
                          no-caption
                          no-system-menu
                          hide-menu-bar)]
                 [label "glui"]
                 [width (/ W 2)]
                 [height (/ H 2)]))
  (define c (new game-canvas%
                 [parent f]
                 [style '(gl)]))
  (send f show #t)
  (send f center 'both)

  (send c STEP))
```

[image: Screenshot of the above]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have Display Zoom setting equals 150% on your Windows system. OpenGL isn't aware about it, you need to scale manually.

```
(define/override (on-size width height)
  ...
  (let ([scale (get-display-backing-scale)]
        [scaled-width (exact-truncate (* width scale))]
        [scaled-height (exact-truncate (* height scale))])
    ...
    (gl-viewport 0 0 scaled-width scaled-height)
```

Comment: What gave you this idea?? I haven't tested this yet, but I did fiddle with that computer because of its high dpi and this makes perfect sense now

Comment: I got stuck with the same issue trying to replace cpu-based render of my game prototype with OpenGL one, except I had 1.25 scale coefficient. Then I remembered my 125% Display Zoom setting and found this article (especially the "Using Display Zoom in a Renderer" part): https://nlguillemot.wordpress.com/2016/12/11/high-dpi-rendering/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not using `(gl-ortho -1 1 -1 1 -1 1)` directly but instead you additionally multiply left and right values by `aspect` in `(gl-ortho (* aspect -1) (* aspect 1) -1 1 -1 1)`. It is wrong, as -1 and 1 will always point to left and right border (if other values are as specified) independently of your aspect ratio. So I would remove `aspect` altogether and use -1 and 1. Here is the code that works for my 16/9 display:

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/class)
(require racket/gui/base)
(require sgl)
(require sgl/gl-vectors)

(define game-canvas%
  (class canvas%
    (inherit refresh with-gl-context swap-gl-buffers)

    (super-new)

    (define (next x)
      (modulo (+ 1 x) 100))

    (define x-factor 0)

    (define/override (on-paint)
      (with-gl-context
       (lambda ()
         (gl-clear-color 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0)
         (gl-clear 'color-buffer-bit 'depth-buffer-bit)
         (gl-color 1 1 0) (gl-rect -1 -1 (+ -1 (* 2 x-factor 1/100)) 1)
         (swap-gl-buffers)
         (gl-flush))))

    (define/public (STEP)
      (set! x-factor (next x-factor))
      (refresh)
      (sleep/yield 1/60)
      (queue-callback (lambda _ (send this STEP) #f)))

    (define/override (on-event e)
      (when (is-a? e mouse-event%)
        (when (eq? (send e get-event-type) 'left-down)
          (exit 0))))

    (define/override (on-size width height)
      (with-gl-context
       (lambda ()
         ;; Changes here
         (gl-viewport 0 0 width height)
         (gl-matrix-mode 'projection)
         (gl-load-identity)
         (gl-ortho  -1  1 -1 1 -1 1)
         (gl-enable 'depth-test)))
         ;; End of changes
      (refresh))))

(module+ main
  (define-values (W H) (get-display-size #t))
  (define f (new frame%
                 [style '(no-resize-border
                          no-caption
                          no-system-menu
                          hide-menu-bar)]
                 [label "glui"]
                 [width (/ W 2)]
                 [height (/ H 2)]))
  (define c (new game-canvas%
                 [parent f]
                 [style '(gl)]))
  (send f show #t)
  (send f center 'both)

  (send c STEP))
```

Comment: The aspect ratio part just squishes the view to include some of the scene beyond -1 and 1 (which, yes, are the edges) so that the shape is rendered as a square (with extra black background depending on the window's aspect). Your code did not change anything for me - it seems it is specific to my computer's drivers. Almost as if windows 8.1 is playing tricks on the opengl libraries...

Comment: (the picture in my question is the largest size the shape reaches)